# New field and joined fields not displaying in attribute table field dropdown in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I joined some fields to a layer and also added a new field. These fields display as expected in the layer's attribute table. Now I want to create an expression for one of the new fields but it doesn't appear in the field's drop-down next to the epsilon symbol. Neither do the joined fields. QGIS 3.16.15 - Hannover.

Comment: I can't reprodcue this behaviour: for me it works fine. That means that somewhere you missed a step. Can you add more details, how did you proceed? What kind of layers do you use: Geopackage? Are layers editable? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I'm new so hope this is the right place to add that this morning when I opened the project I wasn't able to reproduce the problem either.

Comment: So there is no problem at all? When a problem arises, it's often a good idea to save all data + project, close QGIS and restart to see if the problem persists.

Comment: No problem anymore. I'll make a habit of saving, closing, and restarting QGIS in the future.